# Minecraft won't start

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

i have the launcher version 1.3.11 and anytime i run any minecraft version it loads and nothing happens[image: It says Fatal Error] HELP!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the whole .minecraft folder? (backup you saves first)

Answer (score 4):

You're having a NullPointer Exception in your log. Generally speaking, the program is trying to talk to an object but it's not there.

In this case I would highly recommend "reinstalling" the game. 
By this, I mean:

- Go to %appdata%\.minecraft\
- Back up your saved games
- Rename the folder to "old_minecraft"
- Start the Game with the regular launcher
- The %appdata%\.minecraft\ folder should reappear
- Copy your saves into the new folder where they originally were
- Try running Minecraft again